# Received contract offer through one recruiter, then contacted for full time offer at same company by another recruiter. How to proceed?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer

I just received an offer to XYZ, Inc. through recruiter A. Now this opportunity is a contract position and I would prefer full time, but I can take the contract if necessary.

Now I was just reached out to by recruited B looking to hire someone full time (not contract), so that they can offer the same services to company XYZ, Inc., but I need to go through the interview process with recruiter B first; even-though XYZ liked me.

Should I make recruiter A wait to see if I get an offer from recruiter B?

Is it just completely despicable to even consider this, since I already went through the process with recruiter A?

I don't love doing this, but I would really prefer the full time position; especially since we're expecting a baby, and vacation and paternity will be good to have.

Comment: You're worried about being despicable to the company only; let the recruiters be damned.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are getting head hunted by two separate recruiting agencies, then these two jobs are probably not for the same department within that company. In my experience, it is typically up to the hiring manager to determine if, when, and what 3rd party recruiting agency assists with the hire.

Answer (score 5):

**Do not respond to Recruiter B.** B is useless to you. (And if you did, don't sign anything, etc.)

You have actually interviewed with the company and are free to work with them directly now, right? You ought to express your interest in a full time position to them. You can mention the opening you heard from B but I would not even bring B up at all (but you can mention their mail merge if you want).

There are a lot of different situations possible between recruiters and companies, but usually their job is, essentially, to headhunt, make an introduction, and get paid for that. Recruiter B did not do any of that and owes nothing to you and has no claim on your relationship with the company -- and if they advertised something to you, lucky you, don't give them the time of day for that.

If the company folds you into FTE they will likely still pay recruiter A. If there is a contract loophole and they don't have to, then that would be poor business ethics. Recruiter A will immediately stop working with the company, as will other recruiters, but this is between Recruiter A and the company, *not* between you and Recruiter A.

Conversely, the company *already* found you and interviewed you, so Recruiter B is of no use to them in filling either role, at least by you. Do you really think Recruiter B can make a better case for your candidacy than *you* can right now? (Bearing in mind that you have actually interviewed with the company, and B has merely heard of you).

If the situation between the company and the recruiters is more complex, I would expect the company to properly advise you. I can't think of any situation where withholding this knowledge from them can help anyone at all.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Would this still be the case if recruiter B is sending me to company ABC; which in turn wants to offer my services to XYZ. I guess that this might create an awkward situation still...

Comment: @sonar I don't really know what you mean about the relationship between you/ABC/XYZ. You will have to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to kill this opportunity if two recruiters both submit to XYZ.  Typically, two submissions will invalidate your chance.  Don't mess around!

XYZ doesn't want to end up in court with two agencies fighting over the finder's fee.

Comment: This isn't a good answer if it's not justified.

Comment: Justified, my foot. I've been doing contract work just like this for 20 years.

Comment: My very first job that I got through a recruiter, three recruiters actually sent me to the same company. No problem at all. Got an interview, then a job offer, then they asked me which recruiter contacted me first, and that one got paid.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you are, a recruiter told me that a lot of companies have a system whereby the first recruiter to put in the CV for you gets the commission.  So it could turn into a fight between the recruiters.

Anyway, how do you proceed?  Telling recruiter 1 about recruiter 2's job would be unethical.  I'd call the person who interviewed you and ask if the two roles ARE the same and express a strong preference for permanency.  That way you might be able to negotiate getting job 2 without upsetting recruiter 2 too much and getting recruiter 1 paid because they did the introduction.

If the jobs are different you have to treat them separately.  Possible permanent vs definite contract?  I'd aim to prove myself on the contract and get moved over to permanent.

Good luck

Comment: its not 2 recruiters pitching the same Job B is going to contact the OP to A  he will be employed by B and not A

Comment: It's the introduction that matters over here.  If agent A sends my CV to company XYZ they've made the introduction for a certain period of time and Company B would be told "too late" even iif OP let them send his CV through for the permanent role.  My advice was for OP trying to switch his offer to the permie one by talking to the interviewer

Comment: no there are two separate employers this is not the same as two agencies sending the same CV to a single employer - read the OP's Q

Comment: OK I get your point.  OP would have to be nuts to go for company B.  Bodyshop companies like this are probably less stable than a fixed term contract with the client.